# Prevent Apache from starting after apt-get install

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, vagrant

When I `apt-get install apache2` the server starts automatically when install completes, and the default Apache configuration makes everything in `/var/www/` accessible to the client side. Thus if I have any closed source server side scripts or other secret information in that directory before installing Apache, it is publicly accessible until I change the Apache configuration and restart Apache or until I stop Apache.

I can do this

```
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
sudo service apache2 stop
# Finish setting up...
```

And then there is only a brief window where the secret stuff is accessible, but it would be preferable to keep Apache from starting automatically at all and never expose `/var/www/` even for one moment.

Are there any options I can pass to `apt-get install` or other ways to prevent Apache from starting automatically after it is installed?

Comment: I don't know what the behavior is when you compile Apache yourself instead of using `apt-get`. I suppose if you compile it yourself you can find the code that starts Apache after install and disable it. That might be a decent answer if someone can describe in more detail. However the ideal answer to the question as stated would still use `apt-get`.

Comment: Why not just firewall off your server for a minute while doing the upgrade?

Comment: I guess my question is kind of a duplicate of this one on askubuntu.com: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74061/install-packages-without-starting-background-processes-and-services

Comment: Yet another option: Use Red Hat/CentOS distributions, which do not suffer from this or any of Debian's other insanities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

1. Create a file `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` with following content:

```
#!/bin/sh  
exit 101
```

2. Make it executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
```

After this, all packages will be installed but the services will not start.

Once you are done, you can remove the file:

```
rm -f /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
```

Comment: I'm trying this. More info here: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/06/policy-rc-d-do-not-start-services-automatically/ (I'm going to use `#!` though.)

Answer (score 10):

Lots of options:

1. Move the closed source content out of `/var/www`
2. Change the permissions on that content such that the apache user cannot read it
3. Iptables to stop port 80/443 traffic
4. Pass a runlevel environment variable to `apt-get`:

```
sudo RUNLEVEL=1 apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: Wouldn't the apache2 install leave the "current" config files in place?  For example, a template left in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf wouldn't be overwritten, would it?

Comment: I think changing the Apache config (after making /var/www inaccessible using one of the methods in these answers) is implied.

Comment: I mean, I don't think any of these 4 methods will modify the Apache config.

Comment: I think I'm going to use `RUNLEVEL=1` since it seems like the simplest option and it worked in a test, but iptables or some other firewall does feel like the right way.